# How can I read and change details of file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, file, properties, media

I have a .mp4 file, I want to read and change this file details (Right mouse click file -> Properties -> Details tab) . I want to read and change Description property (Title, Subtitle, Rating, Tags, Comments).
How i can do it with nodejs.

Thank so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [ffmetadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmetadata) npm module for reading/writing files properties.

Following is the example from ffmetadata npm site.

```
var ffmetadata = require("ffmetadata");

// Read song.mp3 metadata
ffmetadata.read("song.mp3", function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.error("Error reading metadata", err);
    else console.log(data);
});

// Set the artist for song.mp3
var data = {
  artist: "Me",
};
ffmetadata.write("song.mp3", data, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error("Error writing metadata", err);
    else console.log("Data written");
});
```

Comment: Thank you but when I try, I got error "Error reading metadata { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }"

Comment: Did you read "https://github.com/parshap/node-ffmetadata/blob/v1.3.0/README.md" carefully, it says two dependency must be instlled.

Comment: How do I add metadata to an existing file @pmverma?  I'm successfully creating an **mp3** file. The next step is adding the right meta data for the **mp3's** image. `tempAudioFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), audioFileName);      
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
    return writeFile(tempAudioFile, responses[0].audioContent, 'binary')`